# iframe parent document element

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, parent

This should work according to all the stuff I've looked up, but it just doesn't.

I have a html with a document. It has a div, which contains a specific element which I want to access.

```
<li><a href="FAQ.html#" target="page" id="Faq">FAQ</a></li>
```

The html document also contains an iframe with the FAQ.html, which has the following loadup code:

```
<script>
function loaded() {
    parent.document.getElementById("Faq").style.color = "green";}
</script>
```

However, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?
The error console reports nothing which could facilitate my analasys.

EDIT:
Here's a basic concept.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/32831239/Screenshots/htmlstructure.png

(Unfortunately stackoverflow doesn't let me post images as of now)

The left div should serve as a nav bar. Upon page load, the li entry should be marked with a color (e.g. green).

Comment: Well for one, when you define a function you also have to invoke it. Try putting `loaded();` after your function definition.

Comment: It all looks correct, so there's a problem with some code you're not showing us. As Asad noted, you do need to call the `loaded()` function.

Comment: It works, thank you!
Before I tried the whole process with a frameset and oddly enough it worked without invoking, so I missed this simple step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onload event` of the body of `FAQ.html` to invoke `loaded function`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function loaded() {
            alert("Hello !"); //alert to check if this is being invoked.
            parent.document.getElementById("Faq").style.color = "green";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loaded();" >
...
</body>
</html>
```

Or just remove the function `(no need to use body onload event)`

```
<script>            
   parent.document.getElementById("Faq").style.color = "green";
</script>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Before, I tried the whole process with a frameset and oddly enough it worked without invoking, so I missed this simple step.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <iframe src="test1.html" 
 style="float: right; 
 width: 260px; height: 130px; 
 margin-left: 12px; border: 1px solid black;" 
 name="#boogiejack">
Alternative Content
</iframe>
```

Test1.html content

```
<li><a href="#" target="_new" id="Faq" onClick="javascript:loaded()">FAQ</a></li>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loaded() {
document.getElementById("Faq").style.color = "green";}
</script>
```

Comment: That isn't really what the OP was looking for. The script is going to be inside an iframe document.

Comment: All that matters for the <li> item at the moment is its ID.
The code in question is most likely the second one, which is inside the iframed document, as asad put it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following in your parent

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = urlToYourIframe;

// if this is IE then use attachEvent
if (iframe.attachEvent){

    iframe.attachEvent("onload", function(){
        parent.document.getElementById("Faq").style.color = "green";
    });

} else {

    iframe.onload = function(){
        parent.document.getElementById("Faq").style.color = "green";
    };

}

var el = document.getElementById("iFrameContainer");
el.appendChild(iframe);​
```